# How to handle this in Angular 1.5 component in callback function?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to refactor a 1.4 AngularJS directive to a 1.5 component. I try this by removing the $scope, and replacing it with `this`.

It works fine so far, except: I need to set a `$scope` variable inside a callback function. Like this:

```
this.variable = {};

someFunction().then(function(newValue) {
  this.variable = newValue;
});
```

> But, `this` is undefined inside the callback function.

How could a workaround or a proper way of setting the value of `this.variable` look like?

Comment: This may help understanding why it happens. https://toddmotto.com/understanding-the-this-keyword-in-javascript/ Its quite a core concept to JavaScript. The answers below show you the solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to assign the scope to your function:

```
this.variable = {};

someFunction().then(function(newValue) {
  this.variable = newValue;
}.bind(this));
```

Answer (score 0):

the   `this`  inside your function , refers to the `funtion`  itself , that is why you get undefined.

change the global `this.variable = {}` to `$scope.variable={}`  and call it inside the function.

Comment: I wanted to remove all $scopes, because of the new 1.5 component syntax.

Comment: No prob, i hope that I made clear why your outer 'this' does not work inside the function.